# How to add after each iteration in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to achieve the following:

compute the losses in the previous 25 predictions and sum them before
computing the gradient. I have tried this:

```
loss_summation=tf.Variable(0,dtype=tf.dtypes.float32,name="loss")
xentropy=tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=next_element[1],logits=logits2,name="xentropy")
loss=tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.reduce_mean(xentropy,name="loss"))
loss_summation=tf.assign(loss_summation,loss_summation+loss)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=self.learning_rate)
 gvs = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss_summation,[vars])
with tf.Session() as sess():
      for i in range(25):
                     b=sess.run([loss_summation])
```

However `optimizer.compute_gradients()` complains that
`None values not supported`. How can go around this ?

I am actually trying to implement the following function(feedforward of LSTM) in tensorflow to predict the next word given the previous ones

```
def feedforward(self,x_s,hpre,targets,p_s):


    fts,its,gts,css,ots,output,inputs=[],[],[],[],[],[],[]
        losses=[]
        hprev=hpre
        hts=[hprev]
        loss=0
        losses=[]
        previous_state=p_s
        css.append(previous_state)
        for x,y in zip(x_s,targets):
            k=np.zeros((self.vocab_size,1))
            k[x]=1 
            M_c=np.row_stack((hprev,k))                      
            ft=self.sigmoid(np.dot(self.W1,M_c)+self.b1)
            fts.append(ft)
            it=self.sigmoid(np.dot(self.W2,M_c)+self.b2)
            its.append(it)
            gt=np.tanh(np.dot(self.W3,M_c)+self.b3)
            gts.append(gt)
            cs=(ft*previous_state)+(it*gt)
            previous_state=cs
            css.append(cs)
            ot=self.sigmoid(np.dot(self.W4,M_c)+self.b4)
            ots.append(ot)
            ht=ot*np.tanh(cs)
            hts.append(ht)
            yt=self.softmax(np.dot(self.W5,ht)+self.b5)
            hprev=ht
            output.append(yt)
            inputs.append(M_c)
            loss+=-np.log(yt[y])
            losses.append(loss)

        return fts,its,gts,css,ots,output,hts,loss,hts[-1],css[-1],inputs
```

`x_s` is a list of integers representing words.

```
x_s=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8....,24]
```

targets is the list of integers expected i.e if x_s=0 then next letter is 1

```
targets=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...,25]
```

The loss which is a summation of 25 losses is what will be minimized.

Comment: Please, try to construct a minimal self-contained example so we can reproduce it (e.g. `next_element`, `logits2` or `vars` are not defined in your code). Can you explain in a bit more detail exactly what you want? You want the summed loss of the last 25 batches? Or individual examples? And, do you want to also train during these 25 loss evaluations, or only after you have the sum of those? Maybe giving a bit more of context of what you are trying to achieve with this would make it easier to understand.

Comment: @jdehesa, I have added more context, hope it is clearer.

Comment: You are not using [eager execution](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager) (since you are using sessions), so you cannot iterate tensors with a `for` loop. And in any case, you would have to aggregate the losses in a tensor object (e.g. with a [`tf.while_loop`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop)) before creating any sessions, and without using additional variables. But TensorFlow already implements [recurrent neural networks](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/recurrent) efficiently, do you have any reason not to use the standard API?

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to learn the science behind it before using existing API.

Comment: I see, well that's a good reason for it (almost the only good reason). There is [this series of posts](https://medium.com/@erikhallstrm/hello-world-rnn-83cd7105b767) about RNNs in TensorFlow that you might find helpful. The first post shows how to build a RNN "by hand". It uses `tf.unpack` so you can iterate through a list of tensor slices instead of having to use `tf.while_loop` (which is equivalent but more complicated). The next posts may also be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you need to address here:

1. Is there a good reason not to just use larger batches? Are you trying to implement the [lookahead optimizer](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.08610) or something?
2. You look like you're getting started with TensorFlow. Consider turning on eager execution with `tf.enable_eager_execution()`. TensorFlow 2.0 is coming soon, don't waste your time messing with `tf.Sessions`.
3. Variables are not differentiable. So accumulating the losses in a variable doesn't make any sense.
4. I would make a copy of all the model's variables, and accumulate new values there. Then, after `N` iterations assign those values back to the model. Something like:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential(...)
vars = model.trainable_variables
weight_acc = [tf.Variable(var) for var in model.trainable_variables]
for n,(batch, label) in enumerate(dataset):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    pred = model(batch)
    loss = cal_loss(batch, label)
  grads = tape.gradients(loss, vars)
  for g, a in zip(grad, weight_acc):
    a.assign_add(learning_rate*g)
  if n%25 == 0:
    for a, v in zip(weight_acc, vars):
      v.assign_add(lookahead_fraction*(a-v))
```